# Sent Folder displays conversation thread, even though I removed all the old content. I’m using outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I’m using outlook via google 365. 
Today, I needed to forward the content of an email to a specific person. I deleted some information on the email and only left the information that I wanted to forward. I typed the new recipients name on the TO section and added other email addresses on the CC line.
I clicked send and everything seemed ok until I checked my sent folder and noticed that there were previous dates and conversations under the email I sent.

They do not appear to be inside the email I sent but appear under as a separate date.

My question is, will the new recipient see the conversation thread that i see in my sent box?

I am in the recipient group and only see the message I intended to send without the linked conversations i see on my sent folder.  I’m so lost and retrieving the message isnt an option anymore.

Any help is appreciated- thanks

Answer (score 0):

The recipient will only receive what you intended to send. The reason you're seeing it as a conversation in your sent items will be this flag on the ribbon bar

[image]

If you untick show as conversations, you'll just see the content you intended to send rather than the other parts of the same conversation, prior to you removing content.

Comment: Thank you spikey richie, I was super worried that those previous conversations were Somehow sent as well. 
I’m 100% sure that I removed all the other content or thread & only left the relevant information. 

I need to go into these settings and unclick the box “show as conversation” as I don’t want to see these threads on my sent box.

Comment: If it works as expected, please mark the answer as correct to ensure future users of SU can see the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Your new recipient will not see the conversation thread, it is just a view in your Outlook client.(Just as Spikey said- Show as Conversition)

Comment: Oh thank goodness!!!! This is so tricky, makes you think the recipient can see what the sent folder shows. Thank you

Comment: I tried retrieving the message but it only allowed me to retrieve the ones that hadn’t been read by the receivers. Two days later, I am getting automated messages in my inbox from those receivers as “no preview available” does that mean that just now those receivers are opening their email? What would they see if I that email supposedly had been retrieved?